# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Authentication issue

Tags: identityserver4, abp

ABP version 4.4 APP with identity server with angular EF core

my angular client send the username and password to identity server that is part of my abp application (mean same URL for api and identity server) that returns me token but after very next request for "api/abp/application-configuration" return with CORs error.
same application work for QA local environment with local config.
same call for "api/abp/application-configuration" work on app start because that time token is not attached in request header
i check my app setting CorsOrigins are matching with IdentityServerClientCorsOrigins
no space issue both angular and front end on https but with different port. you can verify with logs. one thing is strange in log no protocol attach @ respond. (domain:1000)

I check and confirm that this is Authentication issue. by comment these two line and Authorize attribute from class
My application works fine. no issue for cors

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();

system log

```
2021-09-04 10:42:24.731 -04:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 OPTIONS https://domain:1000/.well-known/openid-configuration - -
2021-09-04 10:42:24.745 -04:00 [INF] CORS policy execution successful.
2021-09-04 10:42:24.751 -04:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 OPTIONS https://domain:1000/.well-known/openid-configuration - - - 204 - - 19.7919ms
2021-09-04 10:42:24.793 -04:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://domain:1000/.well-known/openid-configuration - -
2021-09-04 10:42:24.794 -04:00 [INF] CORS policy execution successful.
2021-09-04 10:42:46.050 -04:00 [ERR] Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (domain:1000)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a CORS issue, instead it is because your API (the UseJwtTokenMiddleware part) can't reach your IdentityServer over HTTP(s). I guess you got some DNS/Certificate/Network issue to resolve.